# Return object type when calling ASP.NET Core Web API from .NET Framework application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am calling an ASP.NET Core Web API from a .NET Framework application.

The .NET code that calls the ASP.NET Core Web API looks like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(ControllerActionRelativeUrl, requestData).Result;
```

To determine whether there was an error I check `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` value. Currently if this value is `false` I just throw the exception with a generic message "There was an error calling API".

However, I need to handle this better and read a custom error message that is returned by the ASP.NET Core Web API.

In .NET Framework I can use:

```
jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

to get the full response JSON from the ASP.NET Core Web API.

The response JSON from the ASP.NET Core Web API looks like this in case of an error:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1",
    "title": "An error occurred while processing your request.",
    "status": 500,
    "detail": "Problem saving item with ID 10334",
    "traceId": "00-56256d2700dd4d45a12773c05384ca91-1c699f6b471da546-00"
}
```

This JSON is generated by following code in .Net Core API:

```
return Problem("Problem saving item with ID 10334", null, StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
```

I need to get `detail` value (this is my custom error message) in my .NET Framework application. However, there is no field with this text in `HttpResponseMessage` class.

Is there a built-in class in the .NET Framework that matches this JSON returned from the ASP.NET Core Web API?

Or should I just define my own class as follows:

```
public class NetCoreError
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string detail { get; set; }
    public string traceId { get; set; }
}
```

and then map JSON string to this class? Seems like a bad kludge.

Or, possibly, is there some other "official" way in .NET Framework to get the value of `detail`?

Comment: If you define it on your own, use the [`ProblemDetails` class used in ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f5853af24e9ee57a5ad26b8609a87c73defc8b33/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/ProblemDetails/ProblemDetails.cs#L11). However it's also possible that instead of a `ProblemDetails` a [`HttpValidationProblemDetails`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f5853af24e9ee57a5ad26b8609a87c73defc8b33/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/ProblemDetails/HttpValidationProblemDetails.cs) might  be returned although that's usualy only the case if validation fails i. e. a client-side error.

Comment: @Mushroomator thanks. HttpValidationProblemDetails will not work because in this case this is not a validation failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the codes below in your .net framework app :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var jsonObject=JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);
if (jsonObject.TryGetValue("detail", out JToken JToken))
{
    
    string detail = (string)JToken;
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(detail);
}
```

Result:

[image]